# Jquery Form selection for Dynamic Form Element MVC Razor

Tags: jquery, forms, razor, dynamic, dom-manipulation

Partial view(s) HTML: **(Possibly that here we can add something to differentiate the forms)**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = @formId }))
```

Partial View rendering:

- `<form action="..." id="form9803" method="post">`
- `<form action="..." id="form9804" method="post">`

Jquery Selecting / using elements created:

```
$('#form9803').serialize()); //**NoData**
$('#form9804').serialize()); //HasData
```

*Yes, when I force the loop to only run once and only create 1 partial view for  the DOM renders data for 9803's Form*

So somehow my Form's are created but are screwing up the DOM.

Jquery Outputs:

- `console.log($('#form9803').serialize());` **NoData**

  *null* ( not actually null, just nothing thought I'd clear that up )
- `console.log($('#form9804').serialize());` **YesData**

  Phones%5B0%5D.Conta....
- `console.log($('#form9803'));` **NoData**

  Object { context: HTMLDocument → 15693, selector: "#form9803" }
- `console.log($('#form9804'));` **YesData**

  Object { 0: , length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → 15693, selector: "#form9804" }

Any Ideas?

Comment: what do you mean they're "screwing up the DOM"? do you really have 9804 `<form>`s on the page or is that just an ID?

Comment: @DLeh I was referencing the ID's of the <form>.

Comment: so what exactly is your question? some `$(form).serialize()`s are working and some arent?

Comment: @DLeh Correct, I can only assume that when the <form> are populated in the dom the ID isn't separating them enough? - the Jquery will only select the last one created. Much like accessing the main div element within the forms, $('div.phoneData.div' + 9803) -> However this works without issues.

Comment: as long as the forms do indeed have unique IDs, `$('#id').serialize()` should be working. type in `$('#form9804')` to your console and see if you're getting the element you're expecting.

Comment: @DLeh updated above to show outputs, as unexpected as they are

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91205/discussion-between-pakk-and-dleh).

Comment: I actually think I found the issue, being that the parent form, has not yet ended and it ignored the start of the form tag for 9803 but then used it's closing tag, where 9804 was therafter able to be rendered in the DOM.